# BeautifulSoup, web scraping | My HTTP request works (code 200) but when I try to catch the html code, I have a "None" code

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, networking, beautifulsoup

```
import requests, bs4, html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://trouver-ip.com"
ip = input("Choisissez une IP : ")
response = requests.post(url, data={"ip": ip})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(response)

def compare():
    if soup.find("tbody"):
        tableau = soup.findAll("html")
        return(tableau)
    else:
        print("Aucun résultat, foirage de code masturbin")
    

tableau = compare()
print(tableau)
```

Does ever someone had the same problem than me, and by the way, I looked many times on the web but don't found anything...

Comment: Cool - that looks like pything introduced the concept of "scope". Try adding `tableau="foo"` just above the definition of the `compare` function.

Comment: Sidenote: You are not calling `compare()` at any time so `print(tableau)` will result in the output `foo`  (if you did what I suggested above)

Answer (score 1):

`tableau` is a local variable in the function and is not available in the global scope outside of the function. And since you never call `compare`, its never even set in the function. Instead, you could call the function and print its result. Since `tableau` is only once to supply the return value, it can be removed completely from the function. And by passing the soup object as a parameter, the function is no longer dependent on a global variable.

```
import requests, bs4, html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://trouver-ip.com"
ip = input("Choisissez une IP : ")
response = requests.post(url, data={"ip": ip})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(response)

def compare(thesoup):
    if thesoup.find("tbody") is not None:
        return BeautifulSoup.find("tbody").text

tableau = compare(soup)
print(tableau)
```

Note that this function will return `None` if "tbody" is not found.

Comment: And what I'm supposed to do when the function doesn't find anything, I tried with putting "html" and not "tbody" and None code appears again, could you help me more ?

Comment: @Blackax - When the function doesn't find anything, it returns `None`. What you are supposed to do in that case is a design issue. Should the script print an error message? Then `if not tableau: print("pit of despair")`.